# Washing Machines vs. Mixers

Tags: design, motors

The motor in a washing machine oscillates at set frequencies as compared to a motor that spins very fast in a fixed direction in a blender/mixer.

[image]

What I don’t understand however is : Don’t they both have the same job to perform -To mix a liquid (usually water) with solid stuff ?

[image]

The more friction the motors can create between the solid materials( food or clothes ), the more rubbing action there would be, hence a faster operation.

So, why don’t the motors of a mixer spin like that of a washing machine ? Or are there those types of mixers as well ? If so, which one does the job faster ?

Answer (score 2):

The motor in a washing machine does indeed spin the basket containing the clothes, but it does not oscillate. Usually, it rotates in one direction and turns on and off intermittently, which action is intended to mix the soapy water with the clothes. Any other oscillation present in a washer is produced by its transmission and not the motor directly.

Comment: Oh ...I didn’t know that. I always thought the motor moved the bucket back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Centrifugal force] acts on the drum of the washing machine because of the uneven distribution of the mass caused by the clotes. There is also forces act on the drum in conventional belt driven systems which also causes incresing oscilations.

[image: Belt Drive vs Direct Drive]